# Запрос на смену аватарки в инсте (c#) Что не так?

Tags: c#, post, instagram, instagram-api

Всем привет.
Выполняю запрос к инсте на смену аватарки, ответ приходит что все ок, но на деле аватарка не меняется

Может подскажет кто, что не так с запросом?

```
using (var request = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler) { BaseAddress = uri })
{
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");

    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36");
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("*/*");
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "www.instagram.com";

    var resultRequestGet = await request.GetAsync(new Uri("https://www.instagram.com/data/shared_data/"));
    var sharedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharedData>(await resultRequestGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-CSRFToken", sharedData.config.csrf_token);
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Instagram-AJAX", sharedData.rollout_hash);

    MultipartFormDataContent dataPost = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    dataPost.Add(new StringContent("Content-Disposition"), "form-data");
    dataPost.Add(new StringContent("name"), "profile_pic");
    dataPost.Add(new StringContent("filename"), "profilepic.jpg");
    dataPost.Add(new StringContent("Content-Type"), "image/jpeg");
    dataPost.Add(new ByteArrayContent(img, 0, img.Length));

    var resultPostFollow = await request.PostAsync(new Uri($"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/"), dataPost);
    var resultLikeContent = await resultPostFollow.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                   
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код выглядит нормально. Я бы добавил юзингов IDisposable классам, но при единичном запросе это не должно ни на что влиять. `{ BaseAddress = uri }` вот это лишнее, потому что вы все равно далее указываете абсолютную ссылку. BaseAddress нужен для того чтобы потом указывать релативные ссылки. Конечно же, это всё не поможет вам решить проблему.

Comment: Еще я бы посоветовал вам уже слезать с .NET Framework 4.x на более современную версию .NET.